# Pg Dn key returns tilde (~)

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, keyboard

When I hit <kbd>Page Down</kbd> in terminal (I'm using Ubuntu 12.04), strangely I get the ~ (tilde) character. This is annoying especially when I searched my command line history and decided to go to the bottom to get my prompt back.

Say, I have 1,351 lines of history. Found what I was looking for in line 869. I could just <kbd>backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, but I'd much prefer to go to the bottom.

Anyone knows how to change this behavior?

Comment: Do you want to use PgDn to navigate in the shell history? Or to scroll in the terminal?

Answer (score 3):

Try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page down</kbd> or something similar (eg. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Page down</kbd>).

<kbd>Page down</kbd> sends the page down key to the program running inside the terminal. If that's your shell (bash/zsh/whatever), it probably doesn't accept the key combination, and ends up trying to parse the encoded key, which contains `~`.

It's more likely you were scrolling in your terminal program itself, using the scroll bar or something similar, so you want a key that your terminal program accepts directly. You didn't specify which program you're using, but <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page down</kbd> is common. You can also try different modifier key combinations; your terminal's key binding setup might also have more information.

Comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Pg Dn</kbd> gives me ;7~

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>></kbd> to get to the end of the history. If you do not like the key combination, reconfigure it in `~/.inpurtc`.