# how to scroll multiple lines in zsh screen completion

Tags: terminal, zsh, keyboard, autocomplete

Thanks to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84421/pg-dn-key-returns-tilde), I was able to configure zsh to properly scroll one line up or down when hitting "pgup/pgdwn" in a autocompletion menu:

```
bindkey "${terminfo[kpp]}" up-line-or-history
bindkey "${terminfo[knp]}" down-line-or-history
```

But that's not exactly what I would like to do - this only aliases "pgdwn" to "arrow-down"... I would like to scroll multiple lines!

So I figured I needed to create a new widget that would call the "up/down" widgets multiple times... Before calling multiple times, I figured I would just do a wrapper, like this:

```
function _down-line() {
    zle .down-line-or-history
    return 0
}
zle -N _down-line
bindkey "${terminfo[knp]}" _down-line
```

That doesn't work: hitting "pgdwn" just exits the menu and completes the selected entry.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repeat a zle widget an arbitrary number of times when the completion menu is open?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377184/how-to-repeat-a-zle-widget-an-arbitrary-number-of-times-when-the-completion-menu)

Comment: marked as dupe, thanks.