# How to repeat a zle widget an arbitrary number of times when the completion menu is open?

Tags: zsh, zle

I'm using the `zsh` shell, and I'm trying to install a few key bindings to use keys similar to the ones I would use in a Vim buffer, when a completion menu is open.

So, inside the `menuselect` keymap I've bound the keys `j` and `k` to the `zle` widgets `down-line-or-history` and `up-line-or-history`, by adding the following lines inside `~/.zshrc`:

```
bindkey -M menuselect 'j' down-line-or-history
bindkey -M menuselect 'k' up-line-or-history
```

`down-line-or-history` and `up-line-or-history` are described in `man zshzle` as follows:

```
down-line-or-history (^N ESC-[B) (j) (ESC-[B)
        Move down a line in the buffer, or if already at the bottom line, move to the next event in  the  his‐
        tory list.

up-line-or-history (^P ESC-[A) (k) (ESC-[A)
        Move up a line in the buffer, or if already at the top line, move to the previous event in the history
        list.
```

Now, I would like to bind `C-d` and `C-u` to the same widgets, but repeating them an arbitrary number of times, for example `5`.

At first I tried this simple code:

```
some-widget() {
    zle backward-char -n 5
}
zle -N some-widget
bindkey '^D' some-widget
```

It binds `C-d` to the zle widget `backward-char`, but repeats it `5` times.

Then, I tried to rewrite the code, moving the key binding from the default keymap to the `menuselect` keymap:

```
some-widget() {
    zle backward-char -n 5
}
zle -N some-widget
bindkey -M menuselect '^D' some-widget
```

But it doesn't work as I expected, because when I hit `C-d` while a completion menu is open, `zle` seems to execute the default widget bound to `C-d`, which is `delete-char-or-list`:

```
delete-char-or-list (^D) (unbound) (unbound)
        Delete the character under the cursor.  If the cursor is at the end of the line, list possible comple‐
        tions for the current word.
```

It exits the current completion menu, and lists possible completions for the current word, instead of moving the cursor backward `5` times.

If it had worked as I expected, I would probably have ended up using this final code:

```
fast-down-line-or-history() {
    zle down-line-or-history -n 5
}
zle -N fast-down-line-or-history
bindkey -M menuselect '^D' fast-down-line-or-history

fast-up-line-or-history() {
    zle up-line-or-history -n 5
}
zle -N fast-up-line-or-history
bindkey -M menuselect '^U' fast-up-line-or-history
```

But since it doesn't, I need to find how to repeat a `zle` widget when a completion menu is open.

How to modify the previous code, so that `down-line-or-history` is repeated `5` times when hitting `C-d` while the completion menu is open?

Comment: Tricky, this is usually done by the `digit-argument` widget (`bindkey -e; bindkey | grep digit`) though simply inserting those into `bindkey -M menuselect` did not help in some simple testing...

Comment: @thrig Thank you very much for your comment, I will try to learn more about  `digit-argument`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because the widgets ["always perform the same task within the menu selection map and cannot be replaced by user defined widgets, nor can the set of functions be extended"](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#Menu-selection).

However, the following *does* work:

```bsh
bindkey -M menuselect 'j' down-line-or-history
bindkey -M menuselect 'k' up-line-or-history
bindkey -M menuselect -s '^D' 'jjjjj'
bindkey -M menuselect -s '^U' 'kkkkk'
```

The `-s` option lets you specify a literal string that will be input to the Zsh Line Editor (ZLE) as if you had typed it yourself. So, now, when you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, will press <kbd>j</kbd> five times for you, giving you the desired effect.

Note, though, that it's not particularly fast. I can literally see the cursor moving 5 steps up or down, one step at a time.

Instead, if you have [`group-name`s](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Standard-Styles) enabled, you might be better off binding

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to `vi-forward-blank-word`, which (according to the [documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#Menu-selection)) "moves the mark to the first line of the next group of matches" and
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> to `vi-backward-blank-word`, which "moves the mark to the last line of the previous group of matches".